# Is there a module to create time varying spatial plots in python

Tags: python, animation, gis, geospatial, netcdf4

I have multiple .nc files for each time step(say 15-minute interval, 96 files for a day), I want to produce an animated plot of the spatial domain with respect to time. I am new to python spatial plottings. please help

I am able to read the NC file, plot it for single time steps, producing 96 plots for the different time steps. but unable to create an animation out of it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can directly create animations, but HoloViews offers a bunch of nice features for things like that. You might want to check them out:
http://holoviews.org/

This is more a comment than an answer, but unfortunately you need 50 reputation for that.

Comment: Also, there's a special implementation of HoloViews for geospatial data. It's call GeoViews: https://geoviews.org/